# Infinite Loop PrintDocument HasmorePages c#

Tags: c#, winforms, infinite-loop, printdocument

I have problems to print the information in multiples pages, currently it cause a infinite Loop i have some hours surfing in the web for a solution but is not clearly.

```
static void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12);

    e.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 850, 1100);

    float pageWidth = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width;
    float pageHeight = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height;

    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
    int startX = 40;
    int startY = 30;
    int offsetY = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        graphic.DrawString("Line: " + i, font, brush, startX, startY + offsetY);
        offsetY += (int)fontHeight;

        if (offsetY >= pageHeight)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            offsetY = 0;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas?
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite loop"? Why do you think so?

Comment: return; e.HasMorePages = true; generates Infinite numbers of pages for print.

Comment: Why do you set `e.HasMorePages` to true? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please try: http://www.filedropper.com/windowsformsapplication2
I want to print `99` Lines but in each page only can be printed `55` lines, then i need to use another page to print the rest of lines. I tryed to use the `e.HasMorePages = true;` command but it causes a infinite print loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think, I figured out what do you want. I think you want to print 100 lines.

For your case you should have and instance field to keep printed lines count.

Try something like this:

```
var printedLines = 0;
var linesToPrint = 100;

...

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.HasMorePages = false;

    ....


    while(printedLines < linesToPrint)
    {
         graphic.DrawString("Line: " + printedLines, font, brush, startX, startY + offsetY);
         offsetY += (int)fontHeight;

         ++printedLines;

         if (offsetY >= pageHeight)
         {
              e.HasMorePages = true;
              offsetY = 0;
              return;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot! @Hamlet

Comment: Have you seen your mistake?

Comment: Yes, but there is no way to do a for loop?

Comment: All loop control flows are interchangeable. But you should choose which better in your own case.